# Confusion on tangent bundle and trivial bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

Given a manifold say for example $S^n$, I know the meaning/definition of "tangent bundle". But what is the meaning or definition of its "trivial bundle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial $n$-plane bundle over a manifold $M$ of dimension $k$ is the $k+n$-manifold
$$
E = M \times \Bbb R^n
$$
with the projection map $P: E \to M : (m, v) \mapsto m$.